# KDE Accessible always open and unclosable

Tags: uninstall, icons, kde

since today i have a weird icon in my notifications area, its called KDE accessible... it has a close button but it doesn't closes when i press that button.

it also has a process but that process is unkillable... i didn't did any updates or other things, this weird icon showed up today and i can't get rid of it...

the symbol is a blue circle with a human inside

(i cant post pictures because i dont have enough rep.)

hope anyone can help me, this thing is annoying

Answer (score 5):

That tray icon is a manifestation of package [`kaccessible`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kaccessible&exact=1).  I don't see any obvious way to keep the app (which "provide[s] accessibility services like focus tracking and a screen reader") but disable the icon; you might consider filing that as a bug if it's still a problem.  If you don't need `kaccessible`, uninstall it and then quit KDE Accessible via the icon and it'll stay gone.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge kaccessible
```